# How to create Charts in spreadsheet referring the Pivot table data using OpenXML SDK in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, openxml, openxml-sdk

We need to create bar chart and pie chart in spreadsheet with pivot table data using OpenXML SDK in C#. Currently I am using OpenXML to create excel sheets which requires further to create Bar Chart and pie chart.

First, we need to create pivot table with the database data table record and then with the created pivot table data, further I need to create pie chart and bar chart. I don't find any reference solution over internet using Openxml, so it will be great if any sample code is provided to understand and proceed further.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.